# New SSL certificate is not propagated

Tags: https, security-certificate

I have installed a new SSL certificate on my server and removed the old one but when I open the website using new PC and new browsers, I still view the old certificate in the browser.

I have windows 2012 on my vps and I add and remove certificates from `IIS manager > server certificates`

Does the propagation of new certificates takes a time?

Comment: Certificates do not "propagate".  A client connects to a server, at that time the server gives its certificate to the client. If the client does not see the expected certificate, then the server configuration is wrong in some way. But besides that you are not giving any actionable detail for anyone to help you...

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I forgot updating website bindings in IIS. I have set up the port 443 to https for old SSL and I thought it is enough. But when you add a new certificate, you have to edit those website bindings again and point to the new certificate in the settings.